# The union of the power set of a family of sets

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

hoping someone can help me in understanding the union of the power set of a family of sets. Please tell me if my reasoning is incorrect.

Let $F$ be a family of sets. In particular, let $F$ = **{**{1,2},{3,4}**}** = {A,B}.

Then the power set of $F$, denoted $P(F)$, is as follows:

$P(F)$ = **{** {}, {A}, {B}, {{A, B}} **}** = **{** {}, {{1,2}}, {{3,4}}, {{{1,2},{3,4}}} **}**

I am now wondering what the union of $P(F)$ is, i.e. $U(P(F))$. My understanding is that the union would be all the elements of $P(F)$ but as one big set. So it would look like this:

$U(P(F))$ = **{** {}, A, B, {A,B} **}** = **{** {}, {1,2}, {3,4}, {{1,2},{3,4}} **}**

I'm not super sure about what I got for $U(P(F))$ so please let me know if I'm wrong. I would really appreciate a second opinion.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $\bigcup\mathcal P(F)$ consists of all objects that are in any subset of F. These are just the elements of $F$, so $\bigcup\mathcal P(F)=F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. $U(X)$ is the set of all elements of elements of $X$. In other words $t\in U(X)$ if and only if there exists some $Y$ such that $t\in Y$ and $Y\in X$.

Also, you have a mistake in your $P(F)$ because $\{\{A,B\}\}$ is not a subset of $F$ because its element $\{A,B\}$ is not an element of $F$.
So the correct power set  is rather $$P(F)=\{\{\},\{A\},\{B\}\{A,B\}\}.$$

With that out of the way, the elements of $\{\}$ are: none; the elements of $\{A\}$ are: only $A$; the elements of $\{B\}$ are: only $B$; the elements of $\{A,B\}$ are: $A$ and $B$. So all in all the elements of $U(P(F))$, i.e., elements we named at least once during this, are: $A$ and $B$. So
$$ U(P(F))=\{A,B\}.$$

Your answer wrongly lists $\{\}$ as an element of $U(P(F))$ even though none of the elements of $P(F)$ has $\{\}$ as *element*. Your other wrong element of $U(P(F))$, namely $\{A,B\}$ seems to be a consequence of the error you had in $P(F)$ mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I can see why my reasoning was incorrect. To be clear, U(P(F)) is still a family of sets, right? That is, U(P(F)) = { {1,2}, {3,4} }?